# Mysql limit then put in alphabetical order

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to order table by most points then put it in alphabetical order. I have gotten this far but I cannot get it working.

```
SELECT category FROM (
SELECT category from table ORDER BY points DESC LIMIT 35
) a
ORDER a.by category LIKE 'A%'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `WHERE`:

```
SELECT a.category 
FROM (
    SELECT category FROM `table` ORDER BY points DESC LIMIT 35) a
WHERE a.category LIKE 'A%'
ORDER BY a.category
```

**Update**

OP wanted a simple `ORDER BY`

```
SELECT a.category 
FROM (
    SELECT category FROM `table` ORDER BY points DESC LIMIT 35) a
ORDER BY a.category
```

Comment: haha snap, stop answering sql posts/questions before I can ;-), but I would edit the subselect out (not required for desired result)

Comment: I'm getting "#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'a.by' at line 5"

Comment: @AbbyE Oops. Let's try again, last time!

Comment: Thought the 'A%' put it in alphabetical order?

Comment: @AbbyE from your original query, it appears as though you are looking for categories that begin with `A`. If this is not the case, then remove `WHERE a.category LIKE 'A%'`

Comment: @AbbyE `where` clause limits rows, it does not order them. `order by` and `group by` as a side-effect order results.

Answer (score 0):

You can order by multiple columns in a single `ORDER BY`

```
SELECT category FROM table
ORDER BY points DESC, category ASC
LIMIT 35
```

IF you are looking to order the top 35 point total alphabeticall (without regard to order amongst top 35) you can do:

```
SELECT a.category
FROM
(SELECT category FROM table ORDER BY points LIMIT 35) AS a
ORDER BY a.category ASC
```

Comment: Doesn't put it in alphabetical order. :)

Comment: It orders by points first, and then category, which is what I thought you were looking for.  You can add `points` into the fields selected to see this.

Comment: I added an additional solution to my answer if you are simply looking to get the top 35 points total and then alphabetize them.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is the following:

```
SELECT category FROM table ORDER BY points DESC, category ASC Limit 35
```

Comment: Doesn't put it in alphabetical order. :)